# Cordova - Android status bar plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar, cordova-plugins

So this plugin exists : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

But as stated in its doc here : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/doc/index.md

Only show, hide and method to check if visible are available for Android.

Since Android 4.4 release, it's possible to customize the status bar much better - even better now that Android 5.0 came to our way.

So does someone knows if there is another plugin that did it already ? I didn't find anything. Elsewhere, do you think modifying this plugin could be easily done ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: could be easily done? it deppends on your knowledge. Do you know java?

Comment: A little ! Didn't work on it since 6 years and my studies though ^^ So it wouldn't be an easy task for me, but if it takes little to code, maybe I could invest some time to understand and do it. But the better option would be to find something already done, of course !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if changing the statubar color in Lollipop is what you're after, then you'd be pleased to learn I just added that option to the cordova statusbar plugin you referred to: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: Yep, they've changed the location of the doc. It's now https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 1):

For all who had the problem, i solved it installing:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

In config.xml:

`<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#00000"/>`

Thanks for all.